# Passing additional vs one argument into the function

Tags: javascript

I am implementing compose function using `reduceRight` menthod as follows

```js
const compose = fns => (...args) =>
  fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc, ...[args.slice(1)]), args[0]);

const func3 = (x, y) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3);

const func2 = x => x ** 2;

const func1 = x => x - 8;

const fnOne = compose([func1, func2, func3])('3', 1);
console.log(fnOne); // should be 1081

const fnTwo = compose([func1, func2, func3])('3', -1);
console.log(fnTwo); //should be -8
```

the first function is supposed to receive two arguments and return the result to the next function as the only one argument. The problem is that the first function is passing two arguments to the next function instead of one. Let me know if you have any ideas how to fix it. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: When I run your snippet I get the results that I'm supposed to. Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: @Barmar I am getting the right results as well. This is a task requirement that I have to implement

Comment: `fn(acc, ...[args.slice(1)])` means it calls the next function with 2 arguments: the return of the previous function and the second element of `args`.

Comment: @ yes this works well on the first function that has two arguments but the rest that follow have only one argument

Comment: they'll just ignore the second argument that you're passing.

Comment: @Barmar agree with you but something tells me that could be a problem in an edge case scenario

Comment: I think you accepted the wrong answer. If you try it when the first function takes 3 arguments, you'll see that you pass 2 arguments to the 2nd function.

Comment: @Barmar I will double check it !

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the first function outside the `reduceRight()` loop, since it's not being called the same way as all the other functions. It gets its arguments from `...args` and its value should be used as the initial accumulator argument to `reduce`.

```js
const compose = fns => (...args) => {
  let last = fns.pop();
  return fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), last(...args))
};

const func3 = function(x, y) {
  console.log(`func3 got ${arguments.length} arguments`);
  return (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3);
};

const func2 = function(x) {
  console.log(`func2 got ${arguments.length} arguments`);
  return x ** 2;
};

const func1 = function(x) {
  console.log(`func2 got ${arguments.length} arguments`);
  return x - 8;
};

const fnOne = compose([func1, func2, func3])('3', 1);
console.log(fnOne); // should be 1081

const fnTwo = compose([func1, func2, func3])('3', -1);
console.log(fnTwo); //should be -8
```

Comment: I would have thought, given OP's definition of `(acc, fn) => fn(acc, ...[args.slice(1)])`, that the extra arguments could be there not only for the initial function, but for the others as well (should the initial function take less arguments than what's provided). It's unclear what's expected anyway.

Comment: He wrote **return the result to the next function as the only one argument.**

Comment: Yes, the result is passed as only one argument, but the extra arguments are not part of the result

Comment: Error: Expected $.length = 1 to equal 2.

Comment: I am running some test on submitting the answer. The test was done by the person who created the question.

Comment: What does that error mean? The function should get 1 argument but got 2, or the function should get 2 arguments but got 1? Which function is it complaining about?

Comment: @Barmar What do you think about this one. `const compose = fns => (...args) =>
  fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => [fn(...acc)], args)[0];`  it does pass the test as well

Comment: I've updated my answer so it shows how many arguments each function receives. It's the correct number.

Comment: Yes, that looks like it works correctly. Post it as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar here is the test `HeadlessChrome 73.0.3683 (Linux 0.0.0) Функция compose не разрушает исходный массив на входе FAILED
 Error: Expected $.length = 1 to equal 2.
 Expected $[1] = undefined to equal spy on unknown.
     at <Jasmine>
     at UserContext.<anonymous> (tests/suite/compose.js:21:17)
     at <Jasmine>`

Comment: `HeadlessChrome 73.0.3683 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 8 of 8 (1 FAILED) (0.021 secs / 0.016 secs)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! compose@1.0.0 test: karma start --single-run
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the compose@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: `

Comment: `npm ERR!     /home/chrome/.npm/_logs/2019-05-31T23_09_06_848Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1`

Comment: I have no idea what any of that is. I guess it's some testing framework, but I don't understand the output.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't like the added `console.log()` statements that I added here. Take them out.

Comment: I just added the function. It runs its own data set

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're not modifying the `args` variable.

Let's look at what happens in detail:

At the first call of your reductor, `acc` becomes `func3(args[0], ...[args.shift(1)]) === func3(args[0], args[1], args[2], ...)`.

At the second call, `acc` becomes `func2(acc, [args.shift(1)])`, which is `func2(func3(args[0], args[1], args[2], ...), args[1], args[2], ...)`.

You can already see where the problem lies: `args1` is never dropped from the array, because `Array.slice()` creates a copy and does not modify the actual array.

To solve your problem you should instead use:

```js
const compose = fns => (...args) =>
  fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc, ...args.splice(0, fn.length - 1)), args[0]);
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. You're only removing one element from `args`, even though the first function uses 2 arguments.

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be like `func1(func2(func3(...args)))`

Comment: If the first function takes 3 arguments, you'll remove 1 element from `args`, and call the second function with 2 arguments, even though the second function should only get 1 argument.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `func1(func2(func3(...args), ...slice(args, 1)), ...slice(args, 2))`. That's an unlikely way to compose functions. Notice that the later arguments get passed to each function.

Comment: It's hard to see this when the original `args` is just 2 elements.

Comment: you're right, in that case we should pop as many elements from the array as the number of arguments expected on `fn` (minus 1, for `acc`). Edited my answer, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: `fn.length` isn't the number of arguments that the function takes.

Comment: it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length